# добавление графического интерфейса

Tags: python, tkinter

```
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import messagebox as mb
 
    import ind1module
 
 
    class List :
    pass
 
 
    def add_window() :
    def add() :
        trn = str(en3.get())
        name = en1.get()
        num = en2.get()
        # noinspection PyTypeChecker
        trains: List[int] = list(map(int, trn.split(',')))
 
        people.add(name, num)
 
    add_w = Toplevel()
    add_w.title('Добавить')
    add_w.resizable(False, False)
    add_w.geometry('225x100')
    en1 = Entry(add_w)
    en2 = Entry(add_w)
    en3 = Entry(add_w)
    lb1 = Label(add_w, text = "Название пункта назначения")
    lb2 = Label(add_w, text = "Номер поезда")
    lb3 = Label(add_w, text = "Время отправления")
    bt1 = Button(add_w, text = "Добавить", command = add)
 
    lb1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    lb2.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    lb3.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
    en1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
    en2.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
    en3.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
    bt1.grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
 
 
    def load_window() :
    def load_f() :
        people.load(en4.get())
        load_w.destroy()
 
    load_w = Toplevel()
    load_w.title('Сохранение')
    load_w.resizable(False, False)
    load_w.geometry('225x100')
    lb4 = Label(load_w, text = "Введите название файла")
    en4 = Entry(load_w)
    bt3 = Button(load_w, text = "Загрузить", command = load_f)
    lb4.pack(padx = 2, pady = 2)
    en4.pack(padx = 2, pady = 2)
    bt3.pack(padx = 2, pady = 2)
 
 
    def save_window() :
    def save_f() :
        people.save(en4.get())
        save_w.destroy()
 
    save_w = Toplevel()
    save_w.title('Сохранение')
    save_w.resizable(False, False)
    save_w.geometry('225x100')
    lb4 = Label(save_w, text = "Введите название файла")
    en4 = Entry(save_w)
    bt3 = Button(save_w, text = "Сохранить", command = save_f)
    lb4.pack(padx = 2, pady = 2)
    en4.pack(padx = 2, pady = 2)
    bt3.pack(padx = 2, pady = 2)
 
 
    def help_window() :
    help_w = Toplevel()
    help_w.title('увы,поездов на данный день не существует')
    help_w.resizable(False, False)
    help_w ['bg'] = 'white'
    img = PhotoImage(file = 'tenor.gif')
    bt2 = Button(
        help_w,
        image = img,
        bg = 'white',
        borderwidth = 0,
        activebackground = 'white',
        command = lambda : help_w.destroy()
    )
    bt2.image = img
    bt2.pack()
 
 
     def select_window() :
    def choice() :
        try :
            choice_en = int(en4.get())
            res = people.select(choice_en)
            if res :
                for idx, person in enumerate(res, 1) :
                    text.delete(0.0, END)
                    text.insert(0.0, '{:>4}: {}'.format(idx, person.name))
            else :
                text.delete(0.0, END)
                text.insert(0.0, 'В этот день нет поездов')
        except(ValueError, TypeError) :
            mb.showinfo("Выбор дня",
                        "Введите день!")
 
    sel_w = Toplevel()
    sel_w.title('Выбрать')
    sel_w.resizable(False, False)
    sel_w.geometry('225x100')
    lb4 = Label(sel_w, text = "Введите день")
    en4 = Entry(sel_w)
    bt3 = Button(sel_w, text = "Подтвердить", command = choice)
    lb4.pack(padx = 2, pady = 2)
    en4.pack(padx = 2, pady = 2)
    bt3.pack(padx = 2, pady = 2)
 
 
def show() :
    text.delete(0.0, END)
    text.insert(0.0, people)
 
 
    if __name__ == '__main__' :
    people = ind1module.Trains()
 
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('800x450')
    root.title('Главное окно')
    root.resizable(False, False)
 
    main_menu = Menu(root)
    root.config(menu = main_menu)
 
    file_menu = Menu(main_menu, tearoff = 0)
    file_menu.add_command(label = "Открыть", command = load_window)
    file_menu.add_command(label = "Добавить", command = add_window)
    file_menu.add_command(label = "Сохранить", command = save_window)
 
    main_menu.add_cascade(label = "Файл", menu = file_menu)
    main_menu.add_command(label = "Показать", command = show)
    main_menu.add_command(label = "Выбрать", command = select_window)
    main_menu.add_command(label = "Помощь", command = help_window)
    main_menu.add_command(label = "Выход", command = lambda : root.destroy())
 
    text = Text(bg = 'white', width = 97, height = 100)
    text.pack(side = LEFT)
    scroll = Scrollbar(command = text.yview)
    scroll.pack(side = LEFT, fill = Y)
    text.config(yscrollcommand = scroll.set)
 
    root.mainloop()
```

каким способом можно стабилизировать данный код,при запуске и вводе при нажатии кнопку добавить выдаёт ошибку,при необходимости могу добавить код ind1module?

Comment: И? Добавляется?

Comment: добавьте полный текст ошибки. и проверьте пробелы в коде

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “C:\Users\longe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter_init_.py”, line 1892, in call
return self.func(*args)
File “C:/Users/longe/lab21/kljhhkl.py”, line 29, in add
trains: List[int] = list(map(int, trn.split(’,’)))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ‘16:00’ это код ошибки,сейчас ошибок нет(после правок,но и отображения окна тоже нет)

Comment: Поправьте отступы, сейчас код не рабочий вообще.

Answer (score 4):

Коллеги, вот так код работает

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as mb

#import ind1module
 
class List :
    pass
 
 
def add_window():
    def add():
        trn = str(en3.get())
        name = en1.get()
        num = en2.get()
        # noinspection PyTypeChecker
        trains: List[int] = list(map(int, trn.split(',')))
 
        people.add(name, num)
 
    add_w = Toplevel()
    add_w.title('Добавить')
    add_w.resizable(False, False)
    add_w.geometry('225x100')
    en1 = Entry(add_w)
    en2 = Entry(add_w)
    en3 = Entry(add_w)
    lb1 = Label(add_w, text = "Название пункта назначения")
    lb2 = Label(add_w, text = "Номер поезда")
    lb3 = Label(add_w, text = "Время отправления")
    bt1 = Button(add_w, text = "Добавить", command = add)
 
    lb1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    lb2.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    lb3.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
    en1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
    en2.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
    en3.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
    bt1.grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
 
 
def load_window():
    def load_f():
        people.load(en4.get())
        load_w.destroy()
 
    load_w = Toplevel()
    load_w.title('Сохранение')
    load_w.resizable(False, False)
    load_w.geometry('225x100')
    lb4 = Label(load_w, text = "Введите название файла")
    en4 = Entry(load_w)
    bt3 = Button(load_w, text = "Загрузить", command = load_f)
    lb4.pack(padx = 2, pady = 2)
    en4.pack(padx = 2, pady = 2)
    bt3.pack(padx = 2, pady = 2)
 
 
def save_window():
    def save_f():
        people.save(en4.get())
        save_w.destroy()
 
    save_w = Toplevel()
    save_w.title('Сохранение')
    save_w.resizable(False, False)
    save_w.geometry('225x100')
    lb4 = Label(save_w, text = "Введите название файла")
    en4 = Entry(save_w)
    bt3 = Button(save_w, text = "Сохранить", command = save_f)
    lb4.pack(padx = 2, pady = 2)
    en4.pack(padx = 2, pady = 2)
    bt3.pack(padx = 2, pady = 2)
 
 
def help_window():
    help_w = Toplevel()
    help_w.title('увы,поездов на данный день не существует')
    help_w.resizable(False, False)
    help_w ['bg'] = 'white'
    img = PhotoImage(file = 'tenor.gif')
    bt2 = Button(
        help_w,
        image = img,
        bg = 'white',
        borderwidth = 0,
        activebackground = 'white',
        command = lambda : help_w.destroy()
    )
    bt2.image = img
    bt2.pack()
 
 
def select_window():
    def choice():
        try :
            choice_en = int(en4.get())
            res = people.select(choice_en)
            if res :
                for idx, person in enumerate(res, 1) :
                    text.delete(0.0, END)
                    text.insert(0.0, '{:>4}: {}'.format(idx, person.name))
            else :
                text.delete(0.0, END)
                text.insert(0.0, 'В этот день нет поездов')
        except(ValueError, TypeError) :
            mb.showinfo("Выбор дня",
                        "Введите день!")
 
    sel_w = Toplevel()
    sel_w.title('Выбрать')
    sel_w.resizable(False, False)
    sel_w.geometry('225x100')
    lb4 = Label(sel_w, text = "Введите день")
    en4 = Entry(sel_w)
    bt3 = Button(sel_w, text = "Подтвердить", command = choice)
    lb4.pack(padx = 2, pady = 2)
    en4.pack(padx = 2, pady = 2)
    bt3.pack(padx = 2, pady = 2)
 
 
def show() :
    text.delete(0.0, END)
    text.insert(0.0, people)
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__' :
    #people = ind1module.Trains()
 
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('800x450')
    root.title('Главное окно')
    root.resizable(False, False)
 
    main_menu = Menu(root)
    root.config(menu = main_menu)
 
    file_menu = Menu(main_menu, tearoff = 0)
    file_menu.add_command(label = "Открыть", command = load_window)
    file_menu.add_command(label = "Добавить", command = add_window)
    file_menu.add_command(label = "Сохранить", command = save_window)
 
    main_menu.add_cascade(label = "Файл", menu = file_menu)
    main_menu.add_command(label = "Показать", command = show)
    main_menu.add_command(label = "Выбрать", command = select_window)
    main_menu.add_command(label = "Помощь", command = help_window)
    main_menu.add_command(label = "Выход", command = lambda : root.destroy())
 
    text = Text(bg = 'white', width = 97, height = 100)
    text.pack(side = LEFT)
    scroll = Scrollbar(command = text.yview)
    scroll.pack(side = LEFT, fill = Y)
    text.config(yscrollcommand = scroll.set)
 
    root.mainloop()
```

Осталось разобраться, что в `ind1module`